# uniform convergence of analytic function becomes analytic in a region

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that, $G$ is a region in the complex plane and $f_n : G \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic for each $n\ge1$. Suppose further that, the sequence {$f_n$} converges uniformly on $G$ to a function $f:G \to \mathbb{C}$. Show that, $f$ is analytic on $G$

---

I need to the proof of the above result. Can somebody help me please.Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have thoughts on the problem and can share the things you've tried? It helps to provide better guidance knowing those things. Regards

Comment: This problem has been proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39863/sequence-of-analytic-functions-on-u-subset-mathbbc-tending-locally-unifor)

Answer (score 1):

The key fact you need is Morea's theorem and fact that for $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly, $\int f_{n}=\int f$. The condition given is actually too strong (you just need $\int f_{n}\rightarrow \int f$). I hope this is enough for you to construct a proof by yourself.